# is it safe to call a method from two different goroutine at same time?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I have two goroutines `go doProcess_A()` and `go doProcess_B()`. Both can call `saveData()`, a non goroutine method.

should I use **go saveData()** instead of  **saveData()** ?
Which one is safe?

```go
var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup

func main() {

    for i:=0; i<4; i++{
        waitGroup.Add(2)

        go doProcess_A(i)
        go doProcess_B(i)
    }
    waitGroup.Wait()
}

func doProcess_A(i int)  {
    // do process
    // the result will be stored in data variable
    data := "processed data-A as string"
    uniqueFileName := "file_A_"+strconv.Itoa(i)+".txt"
    saveData(uniqueFileName, data)

    waitGroup.Done()
}

func doProcess_B(i int) {
    // do some process
    // the result will be stored in data variable
    data := "processed data-B as string"
    uniqueFileName := "file_B_"+strconv.Itoa(i)+".txt"
    saveData(uniqueFileName, data)

    waitGroup.Done()
}

// write text file
func saveData(fileName ,dataStr string) {
    // file name will be unique.
    // there is no chance to be same file name
    err := ioutil.WriteFile("out/"+fileName, []byte(dataStr), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

here, does one goroutine wait for disk file operation when other goroutine is doing? 
 or, are two goroutine make there own copy of saveData() ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "copy of SaveData()", but `saveData` doesn't use any shared values so there's nothing that could be unsafe about calling it concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Goroutines typically don't wait for anything except you explicitly tell them to or if an operation is waiting on a channel or other blocking operation.  In your code there is a possibility of a race condition with unwanted results if multiple goroutines call the `saveData()` function with same filename. It appears that the two goroutines are writing to different files, therefore as long as the filenames are unique, the `saveData` operation will be safe in a goroutine.  It doesn't make sense to use a go routine to call `saveData()`, don't unnecessarily complicate your life, just call it directly in the `doProcess_X` functions.

Read more about goroutines and make sure you are using it where it is *absolutely* necessary.  - https://gobyexample.com/goroutines

> Note: Just because you are writing a Go application doesn't mean you
>   should litter it with goroutines.  Read and understand what problem it
>   solves so as to know the best time to use it.